# building expect from source (static linking)

Tags: c, linker, tcl, static-libraries, expect

I'm trying to build a statically linked copy of expect 5.45 from source.  I have a statically linked copy of tcl 8.6.0 already built.

I'm running configure as:

```
./configure --with-tcl=$(tcl_root)/unix/ --with-tclinclude=$(tcl_root)/unix --disable-load --disable-shared
```

and then I run `make`.

The issue is it dumps a long angry message about undefined references in `ZLib`, mainly `tclStubsPtr` when trying to build after running ar on libexpect while running:

```
gcc \
    -pipe -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall \
    -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    -o expect exp_main_exp.o \
    -L$(expect_root) -lexpect5.45 \
    -L$(tcl_root)/unix -ltcl8.6 \
    -ldl -lieee -lm \
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64 \
    -wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64/expect5.45
```

Other errors seem to be centered around Zlib inflate and deflate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> angry message about undefined references in ZLib

Add `-lz` to the link?

Comment: wow i'm dumb. other issues can be solved by also linking with -ltclstub8.6, -pthread, and -lutil.